# Matching subdomain to one place then if there is a trailing slash match to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My subdomains are dynamic, and need to be handled by one rule if they're top level, if they contain a second handler if they're not.

Here's what I have :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(www|ftp|mail|webmail)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
#This is successful
RewriteRule (.*) displaylist.php?shorturl=%2 [NC,QSA]
#NOT WORKING
RewriteRule /id/([0-9+])$ viewpage.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

So subdomain.domain.com works correctly BUT subdomain.domain.com/id/1230/ doesn't.

The rule to catch the next line doesn't work and just shows the displaylist.php with all of the relative linking broken.

EDIT:

New rules, rewrite is working but none of the relative files are intact

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(www|ftp|mail|webmail)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
#This is successful
RewriteRule (.*) displaylist.php?shorturl=%2 [NC,QSA]
#Working, but relative files (like css) aren't loading correctly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} id/([0-9]+)/?
RewriteRule ^(.*) viewpage.php?id=%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I imagine that the first RewriteRule matches everything with `(.*)` and rewrites to `displaylist.php?...` - so the next rule never sees anything starting with `/id/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rewrite is working but none of the relative files are intact

Add this to the header of the content generated by `viewpage.php` (between the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Perfect solution, had dismissed it because I thought it would throw security errors on the ajax calls, but it works! - Thanks!